# Can you set a driver to control something based on the Brush Pressure?

Tags: texture-painting, drivers

I am trying to see what is possible with drivers, and the main test I am looking at right now is about setting up a driver to change an aspect of a brush texture based on the strength of the brush. To access the driver, I had placed the brush texture in a material on a mesh object and did the driver set up there. In no way did I get anything to work - but was wondering if anyone has had any luck with this ever and could give some advice?

If I can get it to work, then I'd like to go so far as to use the brush pressure on strength to change frame number so the brush image sequence brush could follow the pressure placed and shift images.

I already have no problem with key framing values in the brush texture and playing those back or scrubbing the timeline, and I also use the timeline to scrub through images in a sequence used as a brush texture or brush mask texture. I just really want to be able to add a driver in some instances so I can change more organically.